# How can I find the last entry of a row when summarize() a table

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a table like this

Table

| Time | Id | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8:00 am | 1 | 2 |
| 9:19 am | 1 | 3 |
| 10: 10 am | 1 | 4 |
| 6:03 am | 2 | 7 |
| 7:19 am | 2 | 2 |
| 9: 06 am | 3 | 1 |

so I would like to

```
Table
| summarize {get the last `Value` based on Time accending}  by Id
```

Meaning I want the result to be

| Id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 |

Is this possible using Azure Date Explorer query language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`arg_max()` aggregation function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction)

For instance:

```
T
| summarize arg_max(Time, Value) by Id
| project-away Time
```